# Camel: importing routeContext into an external camelContext

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-camel

I have a camel context in project A:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext">
    <route id="camelRoute1">
        <from uri="vm:foo" />
        <log message="camelRoute1 completed" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Project B and project C use project A as a Maven dependency.

Each one of the projects B and C defines their own `<routeContext>` (in separate xml files):

Project B:

```
<routeContext id="bRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="barB">
        <from uri="direct:barB"/>
        <to uri="mock:barB"/>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

Project C:

```
<routeContext id="cRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="barC">
        <from uri="direct:barC"/>
        <to uri="mock:barC"/>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

I want each one of the projects B and C to be able to import their routes ("bRoutes" and "cRoutes") into the camel context "camelContext" they inherited from project A.

How could I do this?

If I add

```
<routeContextRef ref="bRoutes"/>
<routeContextRef ref="cRoutes"/>
```

to the xml file in project A, "cRoutes" will not be recognized when loading project B, and "bRoutes" will not be recognized when loading project C.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with blueprint in a good way as it is right now. You could do this with the pure Java DSL but as far as I know you CANNOT import camelcontext from another xml file into the current one.

Basically if you are deploying your camel to Karaf you can use direct-vm to connect projects A,B and C with each other. So instead of direct:barC you'd write direct-VM:C.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Karaf here so some of what you wrote is not relevant to me even if it may work. How do I "import camelcontext from another xml file into the current one"? I have never seen a concrete example to this. Just telling me I could do it is not so helpful.

Comment: I basically said that you could not do it. Like I said above the Camel blueprint, unlike the Java dsl is not designed to import routes from external files. You have to connect routes either with vm or direct-vm depending on where they are deployed.

Comment: How can I use Java DSL to access routes that were defined within a `<routeContext>`?